# Cannot edit data from a table in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I keep on getting this error and I don't know why. Can anyone help me with it?

Error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /item
```

Reverse for 'edit_item_status' with arguments '('lll111',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['item/edit_item/(?P\d+)$']

**models.py**

```
class item_status(models.Model):
    item_code=models.CharField(max_length=30,unique=True,primary_key=True,blank=False)
    item_name=models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    type= models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)  
    price=models.IntegerField()
    choices =({'AVAILABLE','Item ready to be purchased'},{'SOLD','Item Sold'},{'RESTOCKING','Item restocking in few days'})
    status=models.CharField(max_length=50,choices=choices,default="AVAILABLE") #Available,Sold, Restocking
    item_quantity_available=models.IntegerField()
    issues=models.CharField(max_length=100,default="No issues")
```

**views.py**

```
def edit_item(request, pk, model, cls):
    item = get_object_or_404(model, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = cls(request.POST, instance=item)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('index')
    else:
        form = cls(instance=item)
        return render(request, 'inv/edit_item.html', {'form': form})



def edit_item_status(request, pk):
    return edit_item(request, pk, item_status, item_statusForm)
```

**forms.py**

```
class item_statusForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = item_status
        fields = ('item_code', 'item_name', 'type', 'price','status','item_quantity_available','issues',)
```

**urls.py**

```
 url(r'^item/edit_item/(?P<pk>\d+)$', edit_item_status, name="edit_item_status"),
```

**index.html**

```
{% for item in items1%}
<tr>
<td>{{ item.item_code }}</td>
<td>{{ item.item_name }}</td>
<td>{{ item.type }}</td>
<td>{{ item.price}}</td>
<td>{{ item.status}}</td>
<td>{{ item.item_quantity_available}}</td>
<td>{{ item.issues}}</td>
 td>
            <a href="{% url 'edit_item_status' item.item_code %}" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" role="button" aria-pressed="true" > Edit</a>
            <a href="{% url 'delete_item_status' item.item_code %}" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" role="button" aria-pressed="true" > x</a>
        </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

This code however works fine for my other classes that use integer primary key.
I don't know why and
I am totally lost now.

Comment: Django can not match the querypath "edit_supplier" with the entries in urls.py. Also note that the regex `(?P<pk>\d+)` expects a number.

Comment: NoReverseMatch at /item
Reverse for 'edit_item_status' with arguments '('lll111',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['item/edit_item/(?P<pk>\\d+)$']

this was actually error
i tried using on another table too.
Do you have any idea on how to pass a char type from the url?

Answer (score 0):

Well as far as I see from your template your code states

`<a href="{% url 'edit_supplier' item.item_code %}" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" role="button" aria-pressed="true" > Edit</a>`

that you want to go to a view called edit_supplier and pass on the pk.
However, you don't have such a view. You only have:
 `def edit_item(request, pk, model, cls):` and
 `def edit_item_status(request, pk):`

But the url is looking for an endpoint edit_supplier.

You should have an url like this:

```
url(r'^item/edit_supplier/(?P<pk>\d+)$', edit_supplier, name="edit_supplier"),
```

Or if you want to use 
`def edit_item_status(request, pk):` 
to handle the edit then in your template please do this:

`<a href="{% url 'edit_item_status' item.item_code %}" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" role="button" aria-pressed="true" > Edit</a>`

Comment: sorry I copy the wrong part of my code
and actually that 

<a href="{% url 'edit_item_status' item.item_code %}" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" role="button" aria-pressed="true" > Edit</a>

it doesn't work too because i am passing in a Char type primary key.